# One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I am using sqlalchemy orm automap to map my existing mysql tables. And I am using three databases with cross relationship between the databases in my project. I have three DBHandler class. One of the handler is shown below,

```
class EngineDBHandle(DBHandleBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Base_ = automap_base()
        self.engine_ = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:xxxxxxx' \
                                '@localhost/my_db?charset=utf8', \
                                pool_recycle=3600,encoding='utf-8')
        self.Base_.prepare(self.engine_,
                           reflect=True,
                           name_for_scalar_relationship=self.name_for_scalar_relationship)

        self.session_ = Session(self.engine_)
```

I have created table repository classes to access individual tables like

```
class CompanyRepo(BaseRepo):
    def __init__(self, dbHandle):
        # create a cursor
        self.Table_ = dbHandle.Base_.classes.companies
        self.session_ = dbHandle.session_
```

When I try to access my table Classes using APScheduler, sometimes my DAL fails with following error code,

```
One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|users|users'. Original exception was: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.subscription_plan' is not mapped
Job "e4a02f60-7d95-11e7-8314-18a6f713ce75 (trigger: date[2017-08-10 12:05:25 IST], next run at: 2017-08-10 12:05:25 IST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/webapp/server/resources/emailcampaign/campaign_process_resource.py", line 236, in collect_campaign_data
    email_details = add_update_email_entry(email_details, True)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/webapp/server/resources/emailcampaign/campaign_process_resource.py", line 333, in add_update_email_entry
    email = email_repo.add(email_details,True)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/dal/base.py", line 59, in add
    new_instance = self.Table_(**row)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 408, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2969, in _event_on_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2850, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1765, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1652, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1709, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 754, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1631, in mapper
    configure=False)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 426, in class_mapper
    raise exc.UnmappedClassError(class_)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.subscription_plan' is not mapped

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/webapp/server/resources/emailcampaign/campaign_process_resource.py", line 297, in collect_campaign_data
    'error_message': str(e)}, True)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/dal/base.py", line 80, in update_by_id
    self.session_.query(self.Table_).filter(
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1330, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 111, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 122, in _set_entities
    self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 152, in _set_entity_selectables
    ent.setup_entity(*d[entity])
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3521, in setup_entity
    self._with_polymorphic = ext_info.with_polymorphic_mappers
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 754, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1948, in _with_polymorphic_mappers
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2847, in configure_mappers
    raise e
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|users|users'. Original exception was: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.subscription_plan' is not mapped
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:30] "GET /api/v1/users/14791602-7cdb-11e7-9b3a-18a6f713ce75 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/webapp/server/resources/user_resource.py", line 37, in get
    user_record_cursor = user.read_by_id(userID)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/dal/base.py", line 33, in read_by_id
    Exception)
dal.exceptions.CloduraException: (199, 'Unknown Error', 'An Unkown Error Occured', <class 'Exception'>)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:30] "GET /api/v1/campaign/14791602-7cdb-11e7-9b3a-18a6f713ce75/0/undefined HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:30] "GET /client/app/css/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
dbHandle.Base_.classes:  <sqlalchemy.util._collections.Properties object at 0x7fd597a49b88>
inside get fun in user_resource
exception is === in read by id One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|users|users'. Original exception was: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.subscription_plan' is not mapped
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:05:31] "GET /api/v1/users/14791602-7cdb-11e7-9b3a-18a6f713ce75 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/webapp/server/resources/user_resource.py", line 37, in get
    user_record_cursor = user.read_by_id(userID)
  File "/home/admin1/Clodura 2/clodura/dal/base.py", line 33, in read_by_id
    Exception)
dal.exceptions.CloduraException: (199, 'Unknown Error', 'An Unkown Error Occured', <class 'Exception'>)
```

I don't understand the issue. Please hemp me out.